# is it possible to create a PWA in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA, i am curious to know that is it possible to create a PWA in angularjs?
please provide steps to make PWA using angularjs if it is possible to create PWA using angularjs.

Comment: Yes. Plenty of steps here https://angular.io/start

Comment: Yes. Here is documentation https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started and here is step by step tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=othhfZ0mGjU

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing framework-specific about PWAs - your site just has to meet a [certain set of criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist):

- Everything is served over HTTPS
- The design must be responsive
- Your app must be available offline (i.e. it needs a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/))
- You need to provide a [manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest) file containing metadata about your application
- Your app must work in all modern browsers
- Page transitions shouldn't block the app (i.e. you need to show loading screens/spinners if things are taking a while to load)
- Each page in the app needs a unique URL
  All of that is achievable with Angular 1 - it'll probably be easier with a modern framework, but there's nothing stopping you sticking with what you've got, for now at least.

look at this github project https://github.com/addyosmani/angular1-dribbble-pwa